# Surrounding bash command with $(<command>)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was reading up on docker-machine (https://github.com/docker/machine) when I noticed this instruction

`$ docker $(docker-machine config dev) run busybox echo hello world`

I was curious what the `$(docker-machine config dev)` part did, particularly, what is the point of the `$()` bit? `docker-machine config dev` is a command, so does executing it with the `$()` do some bash magic?

Comment: `$(...)` is called a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces a single variable to be passed as argument to program. It's like doing `t=$(echo hello)` will make `$t` equal to "hello". You can achieve the same by doing `t=$(command)` and then `docker $t other-args`